# How do I get the icon of the user's Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icons, nsimage

Using Objective-C and Cocoa, does anyone know how to get the icon for a user's computer (the one that shows under "Devices" and "Network" in Finder)? Not the harddisk icon, the actual one for a user's device. It ranges from a MacBook icon to the Mac Pro icon to a Windows blue screen of death monitor icon.

I've tried stuff along the following lines:

```
NSImage *icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] 
                  iconForFileType: NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kComputerIcon)];
```

But that just returns the same icon all the time, obviously. I've also tried the `iconForFile:` method but I don't know of a file path to use as the parameter. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: +1 for at least trying it yourself first.

Answer (score 28):

```
[NSImage imageNamed: NSImageNameComputer]
```

This will return the icon of the *current* computer

Comment: brilliant! Is there a list of other strings or constants for these "named" images?

Comment: The full list of named images can be found in the NSImage documentation. Also, for the record, you should probably use the constant NSImageNameComputer rather than the literal @"NSComputer", since the constant is the one that's actually exposed as public API.

Comment: changed the literal to the constant. Here the list of all constants http://tinyurl.com/m5qcl5

Comment: @Matt Ball: actually both names are public interface; the `@"NSComputer"` literal needs to be in order for Interface Builder to know where the icon is.

Answer (score 7):

Another place to look for icons:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

You can create NSImage objects with the files in there like this:

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/com.apple.macbook-unibody.icns"];
```

It's probably not recommended to hard-code the value like that, however, since Apple may change the icons' locations. There is a file called IconsCore.h that contains many other constant values such as 'kToolbarDesktopFolderIcon' which can be used as follows:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType: NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kToolbarDesktopFolderIcon)];
```

I believe these constants only work in Snow Leopard, though.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for any other system icons check out Apple's sample project called "IconCollection". http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/IconCollection/listing5.html

The sample comes with a plist file that has the names and codes for quite a few system icons that can be accessed using;

```
OSType code = UTGetOSTypeFromString((CFStringRef)codeStr);
NSImage *picture = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(code)];
```

where codeStr is the string code for the icon provided in icons.plist

Comment: Now at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html