# Get NSImage of generic lcd icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icons, nsimage

I'm trying to create an `NSImage` of the generic lcd icon found in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/public.generic-lcd.icns`. Currently, I load this icon using the following code:

```
NSImage *icon = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/public.generic-lcd.icns"];
```

This clearly isn't a good way to load this image though, because if Apple decides to change the location of the icons this won't work anymore. I can't find a constant that loads the same icon though, like you can do for the computer image:

```
NSImage *icon = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer];
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381915/how-do-i-get-the-icon-of-the-users-mac) about icons, but none of the described methods work for me (apart from the direct URL). So my question is, how can I load the generic lcd image without using the full path?

Comment: Copy the images into your app bundle.  There might be license implications, however, but I doubt Apple would care too much.

Comment: @trojanfoe: That's clearly one solution, but find a constant that works is better... Is there really no way to do that?

Comment: Not if there isn't a constant, no.  You don't need to use the Apple images; you could probably create your own images without too much work.

Comment: @trojanfoe: True, but maybe there is a constant and I just haven't been able to find it?

Comment: I've never seen one; so I don't *think* there is one.