# Is there a predefined Apple TV image?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, tvos

Is there a pre-defined image for the Apple TV to be shown on the device itself? Something like the image that the built-in Settings app is using.

In other words, I'm looking for a tvOS equivalent of [`NSImageNameComputer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1381922/199360).